# Drupal 8 - what is application bootstrapper or auto-loader

Tags: 8, composer, bootstrapping

I was working on a module in Drupal 8, and came across this thread answering a question on class auto-loading for Doctrine annotations:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629137/jmsserializer-stand-alone-annotation-does-not-exist-or-cannot-be-auto-loaded

At multiple places in the above referenced thread, the OP or answerers reference to something like an application bootstrapper. For example, OP updated the question with:

> EDIT: my final solution was to create a bootstrap file with the following content:

Another comment says:

> I put this in my application bootrapper (/app/boostrap/app.php), although it could go in the autoloader (/app/boostrap/autoload.php) as well as long as it follows the composer autoload

Although I think I understand how class auto-loading works in Drupal 8, its relation to composer, Drupal's own bootstrapping (which afaik usually refers to Drupal initialising itself for a page load) and ability to use composer to add dependency on packages for a Drupal installation, I have no idea what "application bootstrapper" means in Drupal 8, or special significance of these files (/app/boostrap/app.php, /app/boostrap/autoload.php).

Am I missing something or were people referring to composer packages (and not a Drupal 8 concept) when they used these terms.

Comment: composer packages bro dont worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep this is because of composer ... you will see one if you install anything using composer. here is an example of an autoloader that is automatically created by Composer.

```
?php

/**
 * @file
 * Includes the autoloader created by Composer.
 *
 * This file was generated by drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold.
 * https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold
 *
 * @see composer.json
 * @see index.php
 * @see core/install.php
 * @see core/rebuild.php
 * @see core/modules/statistics/statistics.php
 */

return require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```